# Can't scale or rotate fabricJs Image, Rect, Ellipse

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fabricjs, vuejs3

As in the title, I'm using `fabricJS 4.6.0` with `VueJs 3`.

I'm trying to simply setup fabric with resizable rectangles.

My problem is accessing the object canvas outside the initFabric method.

I can't resize or rotate the rectangle, just move it.

The only way to make it works is declare canvas as const if I use `this.canvas` doesn't work.

here the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8vzc3bj5/19/

```js
initFabric: function () {
    var canvasEl = this.$refs.canvas;
    canvasEl.width = 1920;
    canvasEl.height = 1080;

    const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasEl, {
        // isDrawingMode: true,
        centeredScaling: true,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        selectionBorderColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)",
        selectionColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)",
        selectionLineWidth: 2,
        borderColor: "gray",
        cornerColor: "black",
        cornerSize: 12,
        transparentCorners: true,
    });

    canvas.on("selection:created", this.handleSelection);
    canvas.on("selection:updated", this.handleSelection);

    canvas.on("after:render", this.updateCanvas);
    canvas.on("object:modified", this.updateCanvas);
    canvas.on("object:added", this.updateCanvas);
    canvas.on("object:removed", this.updateCanvas);

    canvas.on("mouse:wheel", (opt) => {
        var delta = opt.e.deltaY;
        var zoom = canvas.getZoom();
        zoom *= 0.999 ** delta;
        if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20;
        if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01;
        canvas.zoomToPoint(
            { x: opt.e.offsetX, y: opt.e.offsetY },
            zoom
        );
        opt.e.preventDefault();
        opt.e.stopPropagation();
    });

    this.$nextTick(() => {
        var rect = new fabric.Rect({
            left: 100,
            top: 50,
            fill: "yellow",
            width: 200,
            height: 100,
            stroke: "lightgreen",
            strokeWidth: 4,
            zoomX: 1,
            zoomY: 1,
            dirty: true,
        });
        canvas.add(rect);
        rect.center();
        canvas.setActiveObject(rect);
        canvas.bringToFront(rect);
        canvas.renderAll();
    });
    this.resizeCanvas();
},
```

Thanks

Comment: Please create a [mre]. Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/23eap5rs/

Comment: @ChrisG you're right https://jsfiddle.net/8vzc3bj5/19/

Comment: Getting exactly the same issue (using Vue3). It's not a problem with on() handler, the mouse cursor won't set itself to 'scale' arrow on any corner, only 'drag' symbol.

Comment: It's kind of weird...I can't fix it. Did you found a solution? @Marius

Comment: no solution, it is weird :(

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm having the same issue when i store the fabric canvas object in vue store (using vue 3)

Answer (score 2):

Fabricjs does not like having the canvas converted to a proxy. One way to get around it is to use a global variable instead of using the data. You can also just remove canvas from the data() declaration, which will make it still accessible throughout the template and code, but not make it reactive.

See original post [Fabricjs, selection handles shown but not clickable before selected together with other shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64328552/fabricjs-selection-handles-shown-but-not-clickable-before-selected-together-wit)

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue has something to do with vuejs reactivity.

Maybe you could use const for the entire logic and assign the const to data variable at the end of logic.

```
this.canvas = canvas
```

Here is the working demo of it.

https://jsfiddle.net/akshayd121/hjgotm7d/1/

Found a similar question here, although rotate and scale work in the above demo example. Some of them have pointed out that there is some issue with this approach in terms of editing text, rotating and scaling.

[Fabric JS Canvas loses editability and resizability when assigned to Vue data attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71157676/fabric-js-canvas-loses-editability-and-resizability-when-assigned-to-vue-data-at)

Answer (score 1):

for me, I had to use `markRaw` for it to work.

```js
import { markRaw } from 'vue';
...
initFabric: function () {
    const canvas = markRaw(new fabric.Canvas(canvasEl, {
        // isDrawingMode: true,
        centeredScaling: true,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        selectionBorderColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)",
        selectionColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)",
        selectionLineWidth: 2,
        borderColor: "gray",
        cornerColor: "black",
        cornerSize: 12,
        transparentCorners: true,
    }));
    ...
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        var rect = markRaw(new fabric.Rect({
            left: 100,
            top: 50,
            fill: "yellow",
            width: 200,
            height: 100,
            stroke: "lightgreen",
            strokeWidth: 4,
            zoomX: 1,
            zoomY: 1,
            dirty: true,
        }));
        ...
    });
},
```