# Fabric JS Canvas loses editability and resizability when assigned to Vue data attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html5-canvas, fabricjs, vuejs3

I have a Vue 3 Single File Component which houses a canvas element. I am using the `fabric` npm package. If I initialize the fabric canvas in the mounted hook using

```js
data: function () {
 return {
  canvas: null,
 }
},
mounted: function () {
 const canvasElement = vm.$refs['canvas']
 const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasElement)
}
```

The canvas works fine and I am able to resize components, edit text objects etc.

But when I add this line:

```js
this.canvas = canvas
```

then all objects on the canvas lose their editable and resizable nature. (Double click on text doesn't work, the corners don't allow resizing when using the cursor). Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a known solution?

Comment: Do you mean when storing it in the vuex store? if so i'm having the same issue were you able to figure it out?

Comment: I am not using VueX currently. This is a SFC and I was storing the canvas object in the data option of the component

Comment: got it, were you able to get it resolved?

Comment: Yes. It was a simple fix, actually. I removed that property from the data section of the SFC, but continued using it in the component scope using `this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas()` . This was accessible throughout the component and also retained reactivity.

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, here's how I manage to get Vue3 working with a Fabric.js canvas.

1. In your component's `setup` script, create a variable called `canvas` and assign it a value of `null`.
2. In the `mounted()` lifecycle hook setup the canvas.
3. You can now use `this.canvas` in your `method` functions when you need to interact with your canvas.

   ```
   <script>
   import { fabric } from 'fabric';

   export default {
   setup() {
     let canvas = null;

     return {
      canvas
     }
    },
    mounted() {
     const fabricRef = this.$refs.canvas;
     this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas(fabricRef, 
     { 
      width: 800, 
      height: 800
     })
    },
    methods: {
      addText() {
       const textbox = new fabric.Textbox('Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet',    {
       left: 50,
       top: 50,
       width: 150,
       fontSize: 20,
        });
       this.canvas.add(textbox).setActiveObject(textbox);
       }
     }
   }

   </script>
   ```

Why this approach?

From what I've observed, if I created a data property to hold my canvas element, then the elements I add to my canvas are not editable:

Does not seem to work:

```
<script>
// ...
 data() {
 return {
  canvas: null;
}
}

// ...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Fabricjs and vue 3 you can use "markRaw" when adding objects to the canvas. That will allow you to use the reactivity system and still add objects to the canvas that .

```js
<script>
import { fabric } from 'fabric';
import { markRaw } from 'vue'; 

export default {
setup() {
  let canvas = null;

  return {
   canvas
  }
 },
 mounted() {
  const fabricRef = this.$refs.canvas;
  this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas(fabricRef, 
  { 
   width: 800, 
   height: 800
  })
 },
 methods: {
   addText() {
    const textbox = new fabric.Textbox('Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet',    {
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    width: 150,
    fontSize: 20,
     });
    this.canvas.add(markRaw(textbox)).setActiveObject(textbox);
    }
  }
}

</script>
```